# Getting count based on below value

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to get the count based on the above Value and a condition. I am using Oracle 11G

See below Table.

I want to Count of Mr.X where Transaction Type = Email and the above Byuser is System.

CallID      | Transactiontype  | Byuser

---

```
1234     | Email            | system
1235     | Email            | MR.X
1236     | call             | Mr.X
1237     | Email            | System
1238     | Email            | Mr.X
1239     | Call             | Mr.Y
1240     | Other            | Mr.X
```

Final Results will be:

### Byuser | Count

Mr. X  |  2

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I am new to SQl queries. I even not getting an Idea how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this(**EDITED**) :

```
 select t.Byuser, count(*)
 from table_name t join table_name f
 on t.callid=f.callid+1
 where t.Transactiontype ='Email' and t.Byuser='MR.X' and f.Byuser='System'
 group by t.Byuser ;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your quick reply. It has to count only when the above value is  System. Otherwise, it shouldn't count. :)

Comment: As per Oracle, the order of records is not guaranteed unless you use an explicit order by clause. This query presumes that records are inserted and will be returned as per the increasing order of callid. Also, it assumes the next callid is one more than previous callid.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of analytic function `lag` in this case to find the value of ByUser in last row and compare in current row:

```
select ByUser,
    count(*)
from (
    select t.*,
        lag(ByUser) over (
            order by callId
            ) as last_ByUser
    from your_table t
    where transactionType = 'Email'
    ) t
where lower(ByUser) = 'mr.x'
    and lower(last_ByUser) = 'system'
group by ByUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work if the expected order of records is driven by IDs.

```
SELECT 
      NAME,
      COUNT(NAME)
FROM
      (SELECT NAME,
      LAG(NAME, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS PNAME
      FROM MYTABLE 
      WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'EMAIL'
      ORDER BY ID
      )
WHERE PNAME = 'SYSTEM' AND NAME = 'MR.X'
GROUP BY NAME
```